# Upload an image to OpenFire via PHP API service

Tags: php, xml, image, xmpp, openfire

I am building a PHP API that deals with an image upload. The image is uploaded normally to apache server using $_FILES and PHP move_uploaded_file() - this saves the file locally and is now available for a website. I also need to hit an XMPP server (OpenFire) to update an avatar using the same image, during the same process.

I am having trouble figuring out how to approach this, I would like to grab the actual image file data from the PHP tmp/ location using the file reference found in $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'] - this is how we access it when we use move_uploaded_file(). Is the tmp file data still available after running move_uploaded_file()? The name would suggest not so and experiments today reveal a resource before, and false after running move_uploaded_file(). So how could I hit the image data and format it for use it in an xml packet, while still leaving the original tmp file intact for the subsequent move_uploaded_file()? - see below for xml example.

The alternative would be to use get_file_contents() and read the file we have just saved to the filesystem - but that seems silly.

The next bit is doing my head in. OpenFire XMPP server allows allot through the XMPP interface itself. see http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0084.html#examples-multiple for examples of how to upload and set a users avatar.

Someone please point me in the right direction here, I need to send an XML (XMPP) packet to the open fire server - I already have XMPPHP running and connecting to the server with no worries, its the formatting of the xml thats giving me grief.

Example XMP packet from http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0084.html#examples-multiple (Example 1. Publishing avatar data to data node)

```
<iq type='set' from='juliet@capulet.lit/chamber' id='publish1'>
 <pubsub xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub'>
<publish node='urn:xmpp:avatar:data'>
  <item id='111f4b3c50d7b0df729d299bc6f8e9ef9066971f'>
    <data xmlns='urn:xmpp:avatar:data'>
      qANQR1DBwU4DX7jmYZnncm...
    </data>
  </item>
</publish>
```

Comment: Clarify: The issue of move_uploaded_file is not so important here, its more "how can i format an image file into a string" that can be used in the xml packet..

Answer (score 1):

So I got this xmpp avatar issue working using xmpphp library. I wrote this function to initiate the class:

```
/*
 *  arg 1: $file_handle = the local path to the image
 *  arg 2: $file_type   = the file extension, jpg, png etc.
*/

function upload_new_xmpp_avatar($file_handle, $file_type)
{
// XMPPHP class. Used to connect to xmpp server
require_once "xmpphp/XMPPHP/XMPP.php;

$xmpp_host = "xmpp.domain.com";

$xmpp_server = ""xmpp.domain.com";

$xmpp_port = "5222";

$admin_username = "admin_user";

$admin_pasword = "admin_pw";

$conn = new XMPPHP_XMPP($xmpp_host, $port, $admin_username, $admin_password, "xmpphp", $xmpp_server, $printlog = false, $loglevel = XMPPHP_Log::LEVEL_VERBOSE);

try
{
    // load the image from filesystem
    $raw_file = file_get_contents($file_handle);                                                                            

    // get the image information array, width, height etc.
    $image_info = getimagesize($file_handle);                                                                               

    // build sha1 hash of the raw image data
    $image_sha1_hash = sha1($file_handle);                                                                                  

    // base64 encode it!
    $file_data = base64_encode($raw_file);                                                                                  

    $conn->connect();

    $conn->processUntil('session_start');

    $conn->upload_new_avatar_from_file($user_r->user_name, $file_data, $image_info, $image_sha1_hash);

    $conn->disconnect();
}
catch(XMPPHP_Exception $e) 
{
    api_die("xmpp_error: ".$e->getMessage());
}

return $image_sha1_hash;
```

}

Also needed to add a new class function to XMPP.php class:

```
    // adding upload avatar option

public function upload_new_avatar_from_file($user_name, $file_data, $image_info, $image_sha1_hash)          // 08 01 2013 NM adding upload new avatar function
{
    $id = 'upload_avatar_file_' . $this->getID();

    $image_file_size = ($image_info['bits']*8);                                                             // convert bits to bytes.. dur.

    $image_mime_type = $image_info['mime'];

    $image_height = $image_info[1];                                                                         

    $image_width = $image_info[0];

    $xml = "<iq type='set' to='$user_name@$xmpp_server' id='$id'>
                <vCard xmlns='vcard-temp'>
                    <PHOTO xmlns='vcard-temp'>
                        <BINVAL xmlns='vcard-temp'>$file_data</BINVAL>
                        <TYPE xmlns='vcard-temp'>$image_mime_type</TYPE>
                    </PHOTO>
                </vCard>
            </iq>";

    // 2nd xml comand sets the uploaded image as the new vCard avatar 

    $xml2 = "<presence>
                <priority>30</priority>
                <status>Online</status>
                <x xmlns='vcard-temp:x:update'>
                  <photo>$image_sha1_hash</photo>
                </x>
                <x xmlns='jabber:x:avatar'>
                  <hash>$image_sha1_hash</hash>
                </x>
                <c xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/caps' node='http://vacuum-im.googlecode.com' ver='nvOfScxvX/KRll5e2pqmMEBIls0=' hash='sha-1'/>
              </presence>";

    // end vacuum vCard example

    // http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0084.html node and metadata example     

    $this->addIdHandler($id, 'upload_avatar_handler');

    // send the 1st packet
    $this->send($xml);                                                                                          

    $this->addIdHandler($id2, 'upload_avatar_handler');

    // send the 2nd packet
    $this->send($xml2);                                                                                         
}

protected function upload_avatar_handler($xml)
{
    switch ($xml->attrs['type']) 
    {
        case 'error':
            $this->event('upload_new_avatar', 'error');
        break;

        default:
            $this->event('upload_new_avatar', 'default');
        break;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps someone trying to do the same!

Answer (score -1):

No. Once you've used move_uploaded_file), it's no longer in the temp dir. that's why it's **MOVE** and not **COPY**. Nothing says you can't move it, then use copy() operations later from wherever it was moved to, e.g.

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], '/site/file1.txt');
copy('/site/file1.txt', '/size/other/dir/file2.txt');
etc...
```

it's just a file... just because you've moved it doesn't mean you can't ever touch it again for other things.